# JQuery - Toggle divs in newsflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Trying to show/hide severals divs using jquery after each news on my page.

```
<div class="newsbox">
    <a href="#" class="item">Comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Confirm</a>
</div>
```

Want each of these links to show a specific div with content connected to that news. Here are the divs that are hidden by default.

```
<div class="itemComments">
    CONTENT
</div>
<div class="itemConfirm">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

How could I write a JavaScript with JQuery that works regardless the number of news?

Thanks!

EDIT:
To prevent selecting all .itemComments on the page maybe I can select the next element with that classname starting from the element with the clickevent. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but something along the lines of: $('.itemComments').toggle(); and $('.itemConfirm').toggle();

Comment: Well, a script like that would toggle all .itemConfirm on the page. Searching for a script that only toggle the one connected to that specific news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('div.newsbox a').click(function(){
   $('div.'+$(this).attr('class')+$(this).text()).show()
})
```

NEXT ONE :

```
$('div.newsbox a').click(function(){
   $('div.item'+$(this).text()).eq($(this).index()).show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't solve my problem with multiple news. With this script all comments will show for all news.

Comment: do you have multiple classes with same name?

Comment: According to your situation see my next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use jQuery UIs tabs widget? The markup is similar and you can roll your own theme

JQ UI Tabs : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Tried it but didn't find a working solution with multiple tabs on the same page and without using <ul><li> that dont work with my design. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave it a go as well. won't work out of the box. Is there a really strong reason you don't want the LI around the links? They don't show up at all